# Dealing with commas in csv files csv-river plugin

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I am trying to index data present in csv file to elasticsearch server. The problem is the string itself contain multiple "," so during indexing it is giving indexoutofbound exception.

How to handle commas using [csv-river plugin](https://github.com/xxBedy/elasticsearch-river-csv).

Edit:

The example file would be:

```
MESSAGE_ID,PARENT_MESSAGE_ID,THREAD_ID,FORUM_ID,FORUMINDEX,USER_ID,SUBJECT,BODY,MODVALUE,FORUM_NAME,CATEGORY_NAME,LIKES,DISLIKES,IS_ROOT_MESSAGE,IS_QUESTION
244,195,103,4,3,341,Re: The most stupidest program I've ever seen--Amazon,"I know nothing of your case, but I do know that throwing around terms like ""stupid idiot"" doesn't exactly help your side any.",1,"Order Management, Shipping, Feedback & Returns",Sell on Amazon,,,no,no
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to enclose your fields in quotes. If the field contains a quote, you need to escape it with a preceding quote. 
For example:

```
"field1","field2","field3 with, commas","field4","field ""5"" with quotes","field6"
```

Comment: you need to have quotes around all the fields

Comment: I tested and it worked so the example line which I have given is successfully indexed. I think the problem is somewhere else.